# linq как передать переменную диапазона в функцию

Tags: c#, linq

```
var query = from user in users
join phone in decorator.Find(user.id) into phones ...
```

users имеет тип IQueryable.

Собственно появляется ошибка: "Cannot resolve symbol 'user'" в конструкции `decorator.Find(user.id)`

Получается переменную диапазона (user) нельзя передавать в качестве параметра?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Переменную можно передавать в качестве параметра! Но вы должны передавать не `Func<string, IQueryable<Phone>>`, а `Expression<Func<string, IQueryable<Phone>>>`.

Например, такое может сработать:

```
Expression<Func<User, IQueryable<Phone>>> findPhonesByUser =
    user => from AllPhones select phone where user.id == phone.userid;

from user in users
from phone in findPhonesByUser(user)
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Оператор join нельзя использовать таким образом. Вероятно, вам хотелось что-то вроде этого:

```
var query = from user in users
            let phones = decorator.Find(user.id)
            ...
```

или

```
var query = from user in users
            join phone in AllPhones on user.id equals phone.userid into phones
            ...
```

Однако первый способ не сможет быть транслирован в SQL-запрос, а второй способ не использует `decorator`. Вероятно, вам следует пересмотреть архитектуру вашей программы.

Comment: Сейчас как раз используется 2, представленный вами, способ, и такая конструкция повторяется в коде, и хотелось избавиться от такого копипаста. Большое спасибо за пояснение.

Comment: Тогда и задавать вопрос стоило про избавление от копипаста, а не про передачу переменной диапазона в функцию...